# How can I achieve this CSS/JS effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I achieve the top image and then fixed top  nav bar effect of this website? Specifically, the way the top navigation bar scrolls over the top sliding image plugin, then becomes fixed.
http://www.creuna.se/

Comment: Please put at least some investigation effort in your question

Comment: I have no idea though.. It's not that simple an effect. If you don't know how it's done then why bother commenting? You're wasting your time and mine.

Comment: Did you view the source, use the dev tools?

Comment: Oh OK. The scrolling/parallax effects similar to the ones you are looking for are described here: http://smashinghub.com/7-jquery-parallax-and-scrolling-effect-plugins.htm May be some of these plugins will be suitable for you.

Comment: Yeahh I had a look at the source, couldn't make sense of it. Thanks @keaukraine, that's similar to what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the sample and link how can you achieve you may need a JQuery plugin to create such a header slider

http://cssglobe.com/lab/easyslider1.7/01.html

For sticking the Nav bar in the header after scroller past it:
Here is the simple code snippet and demo
HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="navwrap">NAV WRAP</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function fixDiv() {
    var $div = $("#navwrap");
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $div.data("top")) { 
        $('#navwrap').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0', 'width': '100%'}); 
    }
    else {
        $('#navwrap').css({'position': 'static', 'top': 'auto', 'width': '100%'});
    }
}

$("#navwrap").data("top", $("#navwrap").offset().top); 
// set original position on load
$(window).scroll(fixDiv);
```

demo of the above at JsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/5ADzD/1/

Reference post: [Sticking Div to Top After Scrolling Past it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10789936/sticking-div-to-top-after-scrolling-past-it)
Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I get you right, but maybe this can help you :

http://api.jquery.com/show/

With a very high value, you can achieve that the picture comes in very slowly:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#nav").show(6000);
});
```