# How can I change my DIVs position to static when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to attach my `div` to the top of the page as

```
position:static;
```

as soon as I scroll `200px`. How can I do that?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10789936/sticking-div-to-top-after-scrolling-past-it

Comment: You mean position fixed?

Comment: Very low quality question, you haven't tried anything, didn't shared your code, please consider taking a read on how to ask questions in a nicer way

Comment: @AlienWebguy nope, he will need JS

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216114/how-can-i-make-a-div-stick-to-the-top-of-the-screen-once-its-been-scrolled-to

Comment: @Alien I know he will need JS, but position:fixed, not position:static